# How to make somethings like this in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make somethings like this with CSS3?

[image]

My HTML code is like this :

```
<div class="gadget_header">
  <div class="gadget_title">
      <h3>Login</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gadget_container"></div>
```

Comment: Where is your CSS? What have you tried and which part of it did you find to be complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.gadget_header{
  width: 200px;
}

.gadget_title{
  width: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

h3{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

.gadget_container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

This should be a start. There is still a bit for you to figure out.